# WPF ContextMenu to display icons only

Tags: wpf

I'd like to create a WPF right-click ContextMenu that only displays large graphic icons. For example a 3x3 grid of 64x64 pixel icons. Is that possible, by modifying the ContextMenu.Template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply edit the `ControlTemplate` of the `ContextMenu`

```
  <Border >
        <Border.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="64"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="64"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="64"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="64"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="64"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="64"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="icon1.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <Image Source="icon2.png" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <Image Source="icon3.png" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <Image Source="icon4.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <Image Source="icon5.png" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <Image Source="icon6.png" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <Image Source="icon7.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
                            <Image Source="icon8.png" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                            <Image Source="icon9.png" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.Template>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Border.ContextMenu>
    </Border>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I moved the "MenuItem" tags into the ControlTemplate section and it works great.